# How to replace PostgresDriver.simple._ with explicit imports (to narrow down what's imported)?

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I want to take this import

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
```

out of my code and replace it with the various things I am *actually* using in my class

Examples of operators that I am using are `+=`,`===` and the method `firstOption`.

What explicit imports do I need to make to be able to get my class to compile?

Comment: I don't think it would be easy to do, considering that all these helpers are coming via JdbcDriver trait (e.g. firstOption is part of Invoker trait which is eventually included in JdbcDriver: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.0/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc/Invoker.scala)